# Xdebug - "jit" doesn't work with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Following the official documentation I wanted to run Xdebug in "jit" mode. But not working. When I add configuration to my php.ini file then everything works but every request (even when Xdebug listener in PhpStorm is off) takes long (5s to 0.5s when Xdebug is off in php.ini).

So I wanted to make it in "jit" mode or "on demand" but both are not working.

I'm using Windows 8.1 and XAMPP.

This is my config:

[image]
[image]

Comment: First try correcting `.remote_enable=1` to `xdebug.remote_enable=1` or removing the odd line

Comment: Didn't help at all

Comment: 1) Side note: Why do you have that extra leading `-d` in `-d -dxdebug.remote_mode=jit` ? It is not needed 2) So what is the actual command gets executed when you hit Run or Debug? For Debug it will be in the Console tab.

Comment: 3) What are you trying to debug: a CLI script or a web page?

Comment: That `-d` is adding by phpstorm, not from me. I can't remove it. I try to debug website.

Comment: @Klick I'm talking about the extra `-d ` on it's own (the `-dxdebug.remote_mode=jit` bit is fine)  -- this suggests that you have unnecessary empty line in your config (where you are entering that value).

Comment: @Klick Anyway, the web page -- what web server serves is -- is that Apache/nginx/etc ... or PHP's own built-in simple web server? How do you launch it?

Comment: You might want to run through a JIT setup guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-in-the-jit-mode.html & doublecheck your settings or even wipe them & re-configure from the scratch

Comment: I use xampp apache serwer

Comment: @Klick PHP Interpreter settings do not affect PHP that is run by Apache in any way. It can only affect PHP executable that will be launched by PhpStorm (e.g. CLI script or built-in web server). In case of Apache it is the one that runs PHP so all the settings must be configured there (php.ini) or alike. Same with debugger extension from your first screenshot -- that setting does not affect Apache run PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum config that works for me in WAMPServer & Netbeans is

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I see you are configuring for the CLI, so check that the `php.ini` file you have changed is the one used by the CLI.

You can check that by doing this from the command line

```
>php --ini
```

then check the `Loaded Configuration File` to make sure you edited the right file

UPDATE

You also must uncomment, delete the leading `;`, from the `zend_extension` line

```
zend_extension="c:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
```

Comment: path is correct: Loaded Configuration File => C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: Ok, so did you add the line you didnt have? Did it make any difference??

Comment: Yes, I did but no difference.

Comment: OK, did you uncomment the XDEBUG dll load line

Comment: I uncommented this line zend_extension="c:/xampp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll" and xdebug works. But if I swtich off lsitener i phpstorm then every request takes about 5s to finish.

Comment: It works yea. But it's brand new project in symfony 5. I just wrote one controler with "Hello world". If I remove xdebug from my php.ini every request finished in a light speed. When I turn xdebug on in php.ini but listener in phpstorm is off it takes 5s. How to live? :(